# PHP how to implement an array in an already written Held-Karp algoritm

Tags: php

I want to know how the 2D matrix should look like in this array. I want to find the closest way to visit all coordinates in an matrix, with start from (1,1) and end in (1,1). I will have maximum 20-21 different coordinates.

Just to be clear, I did not write this code. I only try to use it, and wants to know what's missing, if it's only the map/matrix perhaps?

Here is the code!
Thanks!

```
<?php

function every_combinations($set, $n = NULL, $order_matters = true) {
    if($n == NULL) $n = count($set);
    $combinations = [];
    foreach($set AS $k => $e) {
        $subset = $set;
        unset($subset[$k]);
        if($n == 1) $combinations[] = [$e];
        else {
            $subcomb = every_combinations($subset, $n - 1, $order_matters);
            foreach($subcomb AS $s) {
                $comb = array_merge([$e], $s);
                if($order_matters) $combinations[] = $comb;
                else {
                    $needle = $comb;
                    sort($needle);
                    if(!in_array($needle, $combinations)) $combinations[] = $comb;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $combinations;
}

function held_karp($matrix) {
    $nb_nodes = count($matrix);

    # Maps each subset of the nodes to the cost to reach that subset, as well
    # as what node it passed before reaching this subset.
    # Node subsets are represented as set bits.
    $c = [];

    # Set transition cost from initial state
    for($k = 1; $k < $nb_nodes; $k++) $c["(".(1 << $k).",$k)"] = [$matrix[0][$k], 0];

    # Iterate subsets of increasing length and store intermediate results
    # in classic dynamic programming manner
    for($subset_size = 2; $subset_size < $nb_nodes; $subset_size++) {
        $combinaisons = every_combinations(range(1, $nb_nodes - 1), $subset_size, false);
        foreach($combinaisons AS $subset) {
            # Set bits for all nodes in this subset
            $bits = 0;
            foreach($subset AS $bit) $bits |= 1 << $bit;

            # Find the lowest cost to get to this subset
            foreach($subset AS $bk) {
                $prev = $bits & ~(1 << $bk);

                $res = [];
                foreach($subset AS $m) {
                    if(($m == 0)||($m == $bk)) continue;
                    $res[] = [$c["($prev,$m)"][0] + $matrix[$m][$bk], $m];
                }
                $c["($bits,$bk)"] = min($res);
            }
        }
    }

    # We're interested in all bits but the least significant (the start state)
    $bits = (2**$nb_nodes - 1) - 1;

    # Calculate optimal cost
    $res = [];
    for($k = 1; $k < $nb_nodes; $k++) $res[] = [$c["($bits,$k)"][0] + $matrix[$k][0], $k];
    list($opt, $parent) = min($res);

    # Backtrack to find full path
    $path = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < $nb_nodes - 1; $i++) {
        $path[] = $parent;
        $new_bits = $bits & ~(1 << $parent);
        list($scrap, $parent) = $c["($bits,$parent)"];
        $bits = $new_bits;
    }

    # Add implicit start state
    $path[] = 0;

    return [$opt, array_reverse($path)];
}

held_karp();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a distance matrix, so an array of arrays, with a number of rows equals to the number of columns.
`$distance[x][y]` should give the distance between node `x` and node `y`. Usually, the distance between a node and itself should be 0.

```
$matrix = array(
    0 => array(0, 2, 9, 10), // distance between node 0 and node 0 (0), distance between node 0 and node 1 (2), ...
    1 => array(1, 0, 6, 4), // distance between node 1 and node 0 (1), distance between node 1 and node 1 (0), ...
    2 => array(15, 7, 0, 8),
    3 => array(6, 3, 12, 0),
);
```

Then the algorithm returns you the best distance, and the path, in an array :

```
$data = held_karp($matrix);
$distance = $data[0]; 
$path = $data[1] ;
```

You can use them fot future processing

```
$path_string = implode(' -> ', $path) . ' -> ' . $path[0] ;
echo "Path = " . $path_string . " with a distance of " . $distance ; // Path = 0 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 -> 0 with a distance of 21
```

Comment: Wow, great info! I just need to figure out a way to convert my x, y coordinates to distances. I guess I will have to loop the coordinates and make distances for EVERY coordinate with Pythagoras and store them in an array like this?

Comment: Example: loop coordinates and loop coordinates inside again, calculate distance with Pythagoras and store distance in the $array[loop1result] [loop2result] = distance. Would this be the right way?

Comment: I don't know the context, but yes it seems the right way. In the original algorithm, the distance are not symetrical (distance from B to A can be different than the distance from A to B, because you can have a different "cost"). In your situation, you can only compute distance where node x < node y and set distance[x][y] = distance[y][x] (even if with only ~20 points, this optimization is not necessary)